# Efficiently determining available options based on prior selections

Tags: design-patterns, algorithms, trees

I'm looking for a known design pattern or algorithm that can be used to effectively determine a set of available options to be presented to a user based on previous decisions.

An extremely simple example of this could be Year > Make > Model where Model and Make are dependent on the prior selections the user made.

I'd like this to scale to an industrial scenario like machine equipment, that can have dozens of options, each with dependencies on the prior selections the user made.  I had considered a decision tree, but I felt modeling it with this many decisions could be a scalability challenge.

What would be the right learning path to pursue to build such a feature?

Comment: I see this was downvoted to close as 'off-topic' however reading the 'help center' scope this clearly falls under the criteria of 'requirements, architecture, and design', so please clarify specifically what is off-topic.

Comment: You are asking for existing software that  applies actions based on rules. Either rephrase your question, or visit the Software Recommendations forum on stackexchange

Comment: I removed the very last statement which is the only piece inquiring to if something like this existed already.  I would like to build this myself.  I will ask separately on the Software Recommendations forum if something like this already exists.

Comment: @KyleBallard learning path sounds like career advice, which is also out of scope. By the way, this subject is far too broad. You'd need a full book on statisticcal analysis, one on machine learning, and one on recommendation systems (the latter topic being extremely competitive for merchants, so that there is some reluctancy to share)

Comment: @Christophe machine learning? I think he is asking for something far simpler, rather, how to traverse a tree of possibilities.

Comment: Agreed, it's not something that needs to be that sophisticated.  I'm actually under the impression this is common in business software I'm just unsure how to go about building something similar.  Regarding "based on previous decisions", I'm referring to the example of Make/Model/Year.  If I pick X belt size, I can only get Y belt material options in my configured machine.

Comment: @FrankHileman Maybe. Although from "*presented to a user based on previous decisions*", I understand that OP expects a self optimizing algorithm, that takes history of articles bought together + success of previous recommendations. So potentially something learning or an adaptative classifier.

Comment: @KyleBallard maybe start here https://blog.statsbot.co/recommendation-system-algorithms-ba67f39ac9a3 ore elsewhere googling for "recommendation system learning".  But as already said, this a subject far to broad to b ehandled in an answer here.

Comment: The decision tree would be my pick, with scalability handled by keeping only a portion in memory (i.e. use data from files, etc).

Comment: @Christophe I'm actually not looking for a recommendation system, it's more like a decision tree.  I'm showing users options in sequential order.  What they pick in step Y determines what is available in step X.  It's not open to interpretation by any learning algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend **NOT** trying to apply a pattern to this and simply hard-code each form.

In my experience the relationship between the criteria is a Business Requirement and as such follows no logic that can be generalised.

For example; your Make and Model might seem like a simple parent child relationship at first, the same as many others. But after implementing itas such, a change request would come in saying

> 'Don't show Models X, Y and Z when the purchaser is in Michigan'

This breaks your model and forces you to make it more and more complicated until it becomes more complicated that the programming language you are using to implement it.

You will revisit the code months or years later and wish you had just coded out each form seperately.